# Localstorage & JSON: How can I delete only 1 array inside a key since localstorage.removeItem requires the entire key

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, html, local-storage

I have this in my localStorage:

```
[{"id":"item-1","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-2","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"},
{"id":"item-3","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-4","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-5","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"},
{"id":"item-6","href":"asos.com","icon":"asos.com"},
{"id":"item-7","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-8","href":"mcdonalds.com","icon":"mcdonalds.com"}]
```

How can I delete only the `id:item-3` when `localstorage.removeItem` requires entire key?

I use this method to update a specific value in an array: http://jsfiddle.net/Qmm9g/ so using the same method I want to delete specific array.

Note that there is already a button to delete. That button I want a function which will delete the entire array (`{"id":"item-3","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"}`) with `ID:item-3`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this would work, I'm not sure if it's the *best* way to do it though. There maybe a better local storage specific way -

```
var json = JSON.parse(localStorage["results"]);
for (i=0;i<json.length;i++)
            if (json[i].id == 'item-3') json.splice(i,1);
localStorage["results"] = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery's [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function along with JavaScript's [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method to remove the entire object like this:

```
$.each(json, function(index, obj){
    if (obj.id == 'item-3') {
        json.splice(index,1);
        console.log(json);
        localStorage["results"] = JSON.stringify(json);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qmm9g/3/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Altough your answer is the same with ipr101, I've accepted his because of he answer quicker

Answer (score 1):

This is my code to delete object from localStorage.

```
 {
"admin": {
    "pass": "1234",
    "task": [
        {"id": "1", "taskName": "assignedTask", "taskDesc": "jhdjshdh"},
        {"id": "2", "taskName": "assignedTask", "taskDesc": "jhdjshdh"},
        {"id": "3", "taskName": "assignedTask", "taskDesc": "jhdjshdh"},
        {"id": "4", "taskName": "assignedTask", "taskDesc": "jhdjshdh"}
    ]
 }


    function filterData() {
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.task);
        //console.log(data);
        var newData = data.filter(function(val){
            return (val.YourPropertyName !== key.value && val.YourPropertyName !== val.value );
        });
        localStorage.task = JSON.stringify(newData);
    }
```