# how to delete a item of a json stringified dictionary in localStorage

Tags: jquery, json, html, local-storage

To support storing dictionary using localStorage, I am using JSON to stringify the dict:

```
Storage.prototype.setDict = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
Storage.prototype.getDict = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
};
```

Now I need to delete a item in this dictionary, how to this without delete the old value and set a new one, which is only an item deleted?

Thanks

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127075/localstorage-json-how-can-i-delete-only-1-array-inside-a-key-since-localstora

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the dictionary, remove the item and replace the dictionary in the localStore as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127075/localstorage-json-how-can-i-delete-only-1-array-inside-a-key-since-localstora) RC pointed to.