# How to remove one element from an array which is created by html5 local storage

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, local-storage

I Am creating one jquery mobile Application. In that iam using html5 local storage  to store some integer values in an array.

```
window.localStorage.setItem("bookMarkedIds",JSON.stringify(resultArray));
```

Now i want to remove one item from the array.
I used 'splice' and it was not working.
Can any one help me out.
Thanks in advance...  :)

below is the code ,

```
function deleteBookmark(newsId){
var resultArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("bookMarkedIds"));
alert(resultArray.length);
for(i=0;i<resultArray.length;i++){
    if(resultArray[i] == newsId){
        resultArray.splice(i,1);
        window.localStorage("bookMarkedIds")=JSON.stringify(resultArray);
    }
}
localStorage.removeItem(newsId);
```

Comment: Could you post more code? what is in your array, how are you trying to delete it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127075/localstorage-json-how-can-i-delete-only-1-array-inside-a-key-since-localstora

Comment: how does your array look like? you want to delete item by index or by value? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/s5aM6/