# How to keep appended data on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `contenteditable` `div` that serves as an editor to allow users to input and save text. Upon clicking a save button, I prompt them to ask what they want to save the text as.

The title is then saved to localstorage and appended to a separate `div`, where they click the title and the text they saved it under will appear in the editor.

The issue now is that whenever I refresh the page, the appended data disappears. Was wondering how I could keep the appended data there on refresh? Also, I need it to still be able to link to its content, not just become a bunch of text in a div.

I've simplified the entire code here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:10em; height:10em; border-style:solid; border-color:black;" id="editor1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="savebtn">Save Changes</button>
<div style="width:10em; height:5em; border-style:solid; border-color:red;" id="Contentable"></div>
<script>
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#savebtn").click(function() {
        var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
        localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.innerHTML);
        titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

        if (titles == null) {
          titles = [];
        } else {
          titles = JSON.parse(titles);
        }
        titles.push(title);
        localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
        var htmlData = "<a onclick=showData('" + title + "')>" + title + "</a><br>";
        $("#Contentable").append(htmlData);
        var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem("userEdits", userVersion);
        editElem.innerHTML = "";
      });
    });

    function showData(txt) {
      editElem.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(txt);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: How can I also remove the data from the div using say a "remove" button? In the event where the div gets too packed and there are some useless titles that the user wants the remove.

Comment: Have you tried displaying contents of `localStorage` at `.ready()` handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ... i hope it works

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .selected{
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:10em; height:10em; border-style:solid; border-color:black;" id="editor1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="savebtn">Save Changes</button>
<button id="remove">Remove Data</button>
<div style="width:10em; height:5em; border-style:solid; border-color:red;" id="Contentable"></div>
<script>
    var editElem = document.getElementById("editor1");
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#savebtn").click(function() {
        var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
        localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.innerHTML);
        titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");

        if (titles == null) {
          titles = [];
        } else {
          titles = JSON.parse(titles);
        }
        titles.push(title);
        localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
        var htmlData = "<a onclick=showData('" + title + "')>" + title + "</a><br>";
        $("#Contentable").append(htmlData);
        var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem("userEdits", userVersion);
        editElem.innerHTML = "";
      });
    });

    function showData(txt) {
      editElem.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(txt);
    }

    function loadData()
    { 

      var htmlData=localStorage.getItem("titles");
      htmlData=htmlData.replace(/\[|\]/g, "");

      htmlData=htmlData.replace(/["']/g, "")
      htmlData=htmlData.split(",");

      var arlength=htmlData.length;
      console.log(arlength)
      for(num=0;num<arlength;num++)
      {

        $("#Contentable").append("<a onclick=showData('" + htmlData[num] + "')>" + htmlData[num] + "</a><br>");

      }

    }
    loadData();
    var selected;
    $("#Contentable a").click(function(){
      selected=$("#Contentable a").index(this);
      $("#Contentable a").removeClass("selected")
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    })

    $("#remove").click(function(){
      $("#Contentable a:eq("+selected+")").remove();
      // Some Delete codes to localStorage here=================================
    })


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do I add at "some code here"? And where should I be adding this?

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Comment: I have a new issue; when I remove the data and I reload the page, it reappears. Meaning it doesn't get removed forever.

Comment: you should delete it also in localstorage

see this code

var json = JSON.parse(localStorage["results"]);
for (i=0;i<json.length;i++)
            if (json[i].id == 'item-3') json.splice(i,1);
localStorage["results"] = JSON.stringify(json);

or simply go here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127075/localstorage-json-how-can-i-delete-only-1-array-inside-a-key-since-localstora

Comment: I understand what it does but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it into my code.. what should I be replacing 'item-3' with?